# Этимология ругательсв

Tags: этимология

Интересно узнавать этимологию ругательств - кем или чем на самом деле мы друг друга обзываем))) Например, откуда взялось слово "жлоб"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Универсальный дополнительный практический толковый словарь И. Мостицкого:**

Первоначально это выражение было синонимом термина «работяга». «Жлоб» — искажённое английское слово «job», в переводе — работа. Во времена строительства Одесского порта лучшими специалистами в этой отрасли народного хозяйства считались подданные, как тогда говорилось, Владычицы Морей. Поэтому на должности прорабов были приглашены англичане, которые в процессе трудовых буден постоянно твердили подчинённым: «Job!». В результате строители порта стали именовать друг друга жлобами. Учитывая, что в то время Одессы как города еще не было, жлоб по праву может считаться первым словом в одесском языке. Долгое время выражение жлоб не считалось оскорбительным, в отличие от фразы «жлоб с деревянной мордой» (сейчас это выражение употребляется крайне редко). Слово «жлоб» стало синонимом таких понятий, как «деревенщина», «хам», «не имеющий представления об элементарных правилах приличия». Свидетельством начала самостоятельного употребления части выражения «жлоб с деревянной мордой» может служить эпитафия на одном из одесских кладбищенских памятников тридцатых годов прошлого столетия: «Ну что, жлобы профсоюзные, теперь вы поверили, что я таки да болел?» (Оnline народный словарь Лингво)
Идишское זשלאָב (zhlob) означает "хамло, грубиян". Восходит, вероятно, к чему-то средненемецкому или арамейскому.
На воровском арго «жлоб» — человек не из воровского мира.
zhlob / zhlub / schlub имеет параллели в английском slob, шведском slabb с исходным значением "грязь, отбросы", трансформировавшимся в "грубый, ленивый, неуклюжий человек". В польском есть żłób со схожим значением. К английскому слову 'job' вряд ли имеет отношение.

Comment: Как же у нас любят в любом ругательстве видеть еврейский след. 
А ничего, что в идише (как и в иврите) нет и не может быть звука ж?

Answer (score 0):

Мне не нравятся предыдущие версии.
Объяснять долго, но если в двух словах, всё за уши притянуто.

Если не ошибаюсь, в польском есть слово zlub (не знаю, как пишется) со значением жмот, скряга или даже прсто "купец".

Comment: По-польски пишется, видимо, żłób, но скрее всего это жаргонизм. В общеязыковых польских словарях не нахожу такого слова (впрочем, может быть, словари бедноватые).